# Spotfire Combination Chart - how can I filter the same chart twice?

Tags: charts, data-visualization, spotfire

My combination chart has two y-axes, one for price and one for value. This data is being pulled from the same table.

Is it possible to filter each of the two axes differently? Whenever I filter the table as a whole, it obviously affects both axes. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It would only affect both if a row had both price and value columns. If it does, then how would you expect the filtering to operate?

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?  Check out [ask] for details on asking good questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TimHutchison this question wouldn't require any code as it's handled natively by the application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, the underlying data set for any visualization is the same no matter the split or the way you choose to display it (in your case, two axes).

If you need the two to react differently to filtering, I suggest you make two visualizations and apply 2 different filtering schemes to them (you will need that, as they are both coming from the same data table).

If this does not meet the requirements, please specify the rationale behind it, we might be able to come up with better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - after trying several different methods, it seems (like you said) that it can't be done. I split out the combo chart into one bar chart and one line chart to make it all work for me. There's no way to filter the same data set two different ways and apply it to the same graph.